# Find folder in subfolders

Tags: power-automate

I have a SharePoint folder structure.

Test/Pay/Active/Owner Holding
>01 Record
>02 Misc
>NY101-Holding/**Report**
Test/Pay/Active/Rock Road
>01 Record
>02 Misc
>NY065-Road/**Report**
Test/Pay/Active/Lego Mars
>01 Record
>02 Misc
>CN456-Mars/**Report**
I want to iterate to each folder and find Report Folder is available or not but to check on in subfolders like Owner Holding, Rock Road, Lego Mars and skip common folder like 01 Record and 02 Misc.

How can I achieve this through Power Automate?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use *Get Folder metadata using path* action.  Point it to your library.  That action gives an easy way to target a library and will get metadata that you can feed into the List Folder action.

Use the List Folder action and the  Id from the Get Folder and gets all folders in the library.

Using the Condition *IsFolder equals True* allows you to cycle through all folders in an Apply to Each.  Another Condition using Name equals the name of your folder will single out your target folder.
You can get the contents of the folder using the Get Files action. You can create parallel actions if you want to process multiple folders at the same time, or you could just do they serially.

Hope that help.

https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/parallel-actions/

[image]